# My Content Management System

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, css

I intend to develop a Content Management System (CMS) like shown in the figure below;

[Figure: Intended CMS design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9WF0.jpg)

1. Is it possible to completely develop it using PHP's standard library?
2. Do I need to use a PHP web framework? If so, why and what framework is ideal?
3. I hope to use MySQL as backend. 
   I hope to use below technologies as front end;

   - HTML5 and CSS3 - hard code by myself (Is there any framework or something make it easy? I heard something lesscss.org)
   - jQuery - to make HTML elements functional
   - Ajax - to avoid page refreshing
   - Bootstrap - to make my CMS responsive
   - Are there any technologies I do use, or any suggestions?
4. I prefer to improve my HTML, CSS, PHP and other technologies by learning and hard coding. So I hope not to use CMS like 
   `joomla`, `WordPress`, etc. Am I right?

**Please note:** I've already searched Google extensively before I put my questions here. But I am unable to confirm what I do next. Your comments are appreciated.

Comment: You can check here https://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/ for php and mysql and you can use framework mentioned in your question. If you are new to php and frontend, first try to clear basics of php, mysql, html and css. Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for the resource you provided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions really look well researched and I think everybody with the intention of building a custom-made CMS has come to this point where they ask themselves these fundamental questions (in other words: good questions!). Now to some answers:

**1)** Yes it is possible.

---

**2)** Although building a CMS in pure, native, hard-coded PHP is possible, I wouldn't recommend it for production. You could do it, and you would largely profit from the experience, *but* there are many little problems (like Routing / User-Management / Authentication / Communicating with Database / Form-Building (like in your screenshot) / etc.) that are already solved by a good Framework.

Also as you are a beginner, you are naturally overwhelmed by the problems and decisions you have to solve/make. This is also a good point why a framework would be a good starter. Although some solutions are sometimes a little too opinionated, they still give you a good structure to start with and most of the times follow best practices of our industry.

Which framework is the most ideal for your project, you'll have to decide on your own, based on your requirements, but some common ones are:

- [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) (probably the most known and most used php-framework, but also very abstract / I would recommend this on a really big project, where you work in a team and you are aiming for flexible maintainability)
- [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) (excerpt from their website: An amazing ORM, painless routing, powerful queue library, and simple authentication give you the tools you need for modern, maintainable PHP.)
- [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) (the little brother of Symfony, info from their website: Silex is a PHP microframework for PHP. It is built on the shoulders of Symfony2 and Pimple and also inspired by sinatra.)
- [FatFreeFramework](http://fatfreeframework.com/home) (from their website: A powerful yet easy-to-use PHP micro-framework designed to help you build dynamic and robust web applications - fast!)

As I used Silex myself many times and also when I began with best-practice PHP, I recommend to start with it, if you decide to write your own CMS. I pretty fast did some Management-CMS similar to your screenshot with it (with their Form-Builder) and was happy with the result.

---

**3)** Again this is up to you. For the backend you will probably use MySQL anyway, if you just need a database. In the frontend using HTML5/CSS you could try jQuery and Bootstrap (and then here their *less* or *sass* implementation).

If you really don't have too much logic for your JavaScript, you could also try to just use native JS, without jQuery. This way you will also learn more about the language and have less vendor-dependencies the user has to download.

---

**4)** If you are really up to learning a lot, then yes, you should probably hand-code everything yourself. This way you also have total control of what code gets delivered to your user. That's a problem with most common CMS: they pollute your code through some other plugins or something and you quickly loose control over your output.

But if you need to be fast there are also CMS that address this issue by giving you total control over your output and giving you creative freedom, like [MODX](http://modx.com/) does.

---

In the end it is up to you and especially the needs of your project. If it's a simple website and you conveniently want to edit the content and also have some starter-help, then I recommend to use a CMS.

If you really want to learn about all this stuff and you have some special needs, then go on and code your custom-coded application. In any way: good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I clarified all what I expected. Thanks once again

Comment: That's nice :) If you need some more clarification, don't hesitate to comment. You should probably wait for some other answers, and accept the one that helped you the most!